# Verify Error while invoke static function in playframework controller

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, verifyerror

I am trying to invoke a static function (Users.dashboard()) at runtime and I am getting a Verify Error exception. Users class inherits CRUD.java and does not take any params.

In Home.index():

```
   public class Home extends Controller {

    public static void index() {

        for (Class<CRUD> clazz : play.Play.classloader
                        .getAssignableClasses(CRUD.class)) {
                    Dashboard d;
                    try {

                        Method m = clazz.getMethod("dashboard");
                        if (m != null) {
                            d = (Dashboard) m.invoke(clazz.newInstance(), new Object[] {});
                        }

                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
    render(dashboards);
}
```

Console Output:

```
@69iahfk3j
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /home

Oops: VerifyError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception VerifyError: (class: controllers/Home, method: index signature: ()V) Register 1 contains wrong type

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:242)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:284)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: controllers/Home, method: index signature: ()V) Register 1 contains wrong type
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at play.utils.Java.findActionMethod(Java.java:98)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:602)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:85)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception stacktrace and Home.index() method. also along with the Application controller code, includes at least line 13

Comment: @green updated question above.

Answer (score 1):

Public static methods in controllers are enhanced by Play so invocation on these methods can be problematic.

Did you annotation this method with @Util if it is a utility method ?

If you just wan to redirect to dashboard in this case, you can simply use redirect on the action, something like

```
redirect("Users.dashboard");
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect. I making a list of dashboards (created through reflection) and rendering the list on the current page. I will see if it works with @Util